# How to add id field to object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

How I can add a unique id to each object in the JSON array using JavaScript

```
[
 { name: 'Yosi'},
 { name: 'Ben' },
 { name: 'Dan' },
 { name: 'Erez'}
]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
 {id: 1, name: 'yosii'},
 {id: 2, name: 'ben'},
    ...
]
```

Comment: You can't do this with just JSON.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: What environment do you want to do this in? What tool do you want to do it with? For instance, JavaScript on a browser or in Node.js? [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) from a command prompt? Python? PHP? Swift?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder with JavaScript :) thanks

Comment: JSON is a *text format*, what is shown here an array of objects. Nothing to do with JSON, which I've edited out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that

```
const data = [
    { name: 'yosii' },
    { name: 'ben' },
    { name: 'david' },
    { name: 'igal' },
    { name: 'gavry' },
    { name: 'Ada' },
    { name: 'Adaline' }
];

const payload = data.map((item, index) => {
    return {
        id: index +1,
        ...item
    }
});

console.log(payload);
```

Return should be like that:

[image]

Comment: Please do not use pictures to show data. You can easily copy and paste the result of running `console.log(JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2))` into the answer. Also, an explanation of what the code does makes every answer better.